# Delphi SQLite Error: Constraint Failed

Tags: sqlite, delphi, zeos

I am having this common error and can not figure what it's causing that

This is the procedure to import data from CSV file

```
procedure TForm1.importarData;
var
  S,D: TStringList;
  fecha:TDate;
  hora:TTime;
  i,j: Integer;
  FileName,Aux: String;
  fExport : TextFile;
  query:String;
  rcDb:TextFile;
begin
  S := TStringList.Create;
  D := TStringList.Create;

  D.Clear;
  S.Clear;

  OpenDialog1.Filter := 'Only CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv';
  FileName:='';
  OpenDialog1.FileName:='';

  //fecha:=nil;
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      S.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);

      for I := 1 downto S.Count-1 do
        begin
          D.Clear;
          D.CommaText := s[i];

          for J := 0 to D.Count-1 do
            D[J] := StringReplace(D[J], '_', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);


          FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:= 'dd mm yyyy';

            //260234920,John_Smith,Jane_Smith,Janet_Smith,Ryan_Smith,201_CENTRE_STREET,Nowhere,AB,T0J111,403-555-5555,smith@email.com,200,2523,2017,12345678,12-10-1971,12-10-1987,12-10-2003,12-10-2004

          //Showmessage(D[1]);

          query:='Insert Into RFID(CID,PrM,AddM1,AddM2,AddM3,Address,City,Province,Postal,Phone,Email,Paid,MID,MYear,MDob,MDob1,MDob2,MDob3,Pal) Values(';                //    "'++'",
          query:=query+'"'+D[0]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[1]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[2]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[3]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[4]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[5]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[6]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[7]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[8]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[9]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[10]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[11]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[12]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[13]+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', StrToDate(D[15]))+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', StrToDate(D[16]))+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', StrToDate(D[17]))+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', StrToDate(D[18]))+'",';
          query:=query+'"'+D[14]+'"';
          query:=query+')';

          ZQuery1.Close;
          ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
          ZQuery1.SQL.Add(query);
          ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
          //showmessage('Done')
        end;
    end;
  S.Free;
  D.Free;
end;
```

The Result of query before executing the SQL

> 'Insert Into
>   RFID(CID,PrM,AddM1,AddM2,AddM3,Address,City,Province,Postal,Phone,Email,Paid,MID,MYear,MDob,MDob1,MDob2,MDob3,Pal)
>   Values("260234920","John Smith","Jane Smith","Janet Smith","Ryan
>   Smith","201 CENTRE
>   STREET","Nowhere","AB","T0J111","403-555-5555","smith@email.com","200","2523","2017","1971-10-12","1987-10-12","2003-10-12","2004-10-12","12345678")'

And this is the DDL from the SQLite database

```
CREATE TABLE [RFID](
    [CID] VARCHAR(16), 
    [PrM] VARCHAR(32), 
    [AddM1] VARCHAR(32), 
    [AddM2] VARCHAR(32), 
    [AddM3] VARCHAR(32), 
    [Address] VARCHAR(512), 
    [City] VARCHAR(64), 
    [Province] VARCHAR(64), 
    [Postal] VARCHAR(16), 
    [Phone] VARCHAR(32), 
    [Email] VARCHAR(256), 
    [Paid] VARCHAR(8), 
    [MID] VARCHAR(4), 
    [MYear] VARCHAR(4), 
    [MDob] DATE, 
    [MDob1] DATE, 
    [Mdob2] DATE, 
    [MDob3] DATE, 
    [PAL] VARCHAR(64));
```

Comment: There's no constraint presented here. Just a hint, better use parameters with a prepared SQL command.

Comment: You should better create an index of CID, which is your primary key (even if SQlite3 has a Integer primary key built-in, which is always to be preferred). Also note that VARCHAR() is of no need under SQLite3. Just use TEXT.

Comment: so what was the errormessage ?

Comment: SQLite Error: Constraint Failed

Comment: I set the CID field as primary key and changed it to Integer, the error still appearing

Comment: @Victoria what do you mean with "use parameters with a prepared SQL command" I can not understand

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by creating a new field named ID of type intger as primary key, not null and with an autoincrement, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [RFID](
    [ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    [CID] INTEGER(16) UNIQUE, 
    [PrM] VARCHAR(32), 
    [AddM1] VARCHAR(32), 
    [AddM2] VARCHAR(32), 
    [AddM3] VARCHAR(32), 
    [Address] VARCHAR(512), 
    [City] VARCHAR(64), 
    [Province] VARCHAR(64), 
    [Postal] VARCHAR(16), 
    [Phone] VARCHAR(32), 
    [Email] VARCHAR(256), 
    [Paid] VARCHAR(8), 
    [MID] VARCHAR(4), 
    [MYear] VARCHAR(4), 
    [MDob] DATE, 
    [MDob1] DATE, 
    [Mdob2] DATE, 
    [MDob3] DATE, 
    [PAL] VARCHAR(64));
```